# Ruby on Rails upgrade Mongoid to version 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Rails application which was using Mongoid 4.0.2. I upgraded Mongoid to version 5.0.0 and start getting this error

```
....gems/2.2.0/gems/less-rails-2.7.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:19:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `register_preprocessor' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How to fix this issue or is any manual how to upgrade Mongoid to version 5.0.0 ?

Gemfile

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0.beta4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jQuery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#new gems
#database
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0.beta'
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem 'bson_ext'
#stile
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mongo'
gem "figaro"
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'rubyzip'
#gem 'sidekiq_status'
#gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'

# rails specific capistrano funcitons
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-rails-console'

# integrate bundler with capistrano
gem 'capistrano-bundler'

# if you are using RBENV
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', "~> 2.0"
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'

gem 'capistrano-passenger'
gem 'utf8-cleaner'
gem "devise"
gem 'rollbar', '~> 1.5.3'


#gem 'bson', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'thin'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  #new gems
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'better_errors'
  #gem 'mongoid-rspec', '~> 2.1.0'


end
```

Comment: we need the full backtrace.

Comment: I tried to upgrade mongoid in an existing app of mine from 4.0.2 to 5.0.0.beta and could not reproduce the same problem. Rails version = 4.2.1 What is your Rails version?

Comment: also, please include `Gemfile`

Comment: Rails version - Rails 4.2.0.beta4

Comment: When you upgraded your app to 5.0.0 did you change anything in your mongoid.yml file ?

Comment: It complained about not having a `clients` entry in mongoid.yml, which basically made me replace `sessions` with `clients` and the server booted nicely.

Comment: I just changed sessions to clients and now it is complaining `Mongoid::Errors::NoClientConfig: 
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a client named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new client, Mongoid could not find a client configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the clients key that a configuration exists for 'default'.
`

Comment: development:
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  clients:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: myapp_development
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:

Comment: it is same as my config

Comment: Have you tried having mongoid regenerate its config file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the error has appeared again in less-rails. The error is not related to Mongoid at all. I started getting the error a couple of days ago on my development server. I decided to check Github to see if an issue was reported about this. I found the following issue addressing the error.

https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/pull/112

I changed my Gemfile to the following as provided on the link which corrected the error.

```
gem "less-rails", :git => 'https://github.com/suzan2go/less-rails.git', :branch => 'fix-nomethoderror-for-sprockets3'
```

As of now this solution has not been applied to the gem. I guess it will be soon.

Comment: Hopefully this is resolved really soon, the git source provided by suzan2go  works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most important thing to look for while upgrading to Mongoid 5 is `mongoid.yml`

From:

```
<%= rails_env %>:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: <%= mongodb_database %>
      hosts:
        - <%= mongodb_staging_host %>
        username: <%= mongodb_user %>
        password: <%= mongodb_password %>
      options:
        read: :primary_preferred
```

To:

```
<%= rails_env %>:
  clients:
    default:
      database: <%= mongodb_database %>
      hosts:
        - <%= mongodb_staging_host %>
      options:
        user: <%= mongodb_user %>
        password: <%= mongodb_password %>
        read:
          mode: :primary_preferred
```

1. Change `sessions` to `clients`
2. Move `username` (will become `user`) and `password` into `options`
3. change `read` mode as shown, if you have any.

Bottomline is to check mongoid.yml thoroughly while comparing with [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Here how I fixed this issue

1. Removed from Gemfile `gem "less-rails"`
2. From application.rb removed `require "mongo"`
3. In mongoid.yml changed `sessions:` to `clients:`